# Is it correct to say "Children in Asia often have private tutorials after official school to help them pass exams to get to higher grades"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This happens in many Asian countries.

Say, students study math, chemistry, physics etc at school (primary/secondary or High school). But, a lot of them don't understand these subjects well enough.

And in order to "**pass exams to get to higher grades**" (I am not sure I am saying it correctly, these students need to pass the final chemistry/physics/etc exam at the end of each year to get to higher grade), they need to "**attend some private tutorials / private lessons after official school**".

In these private tutorials / private lessons, their tutors may not teach them the theory of these subjects because the students learned them in their official school. The tutors may focus on helping doing exercises of these subjects in stead.

Is it correct to say "**Children in Asia often have private tutorials/lessons after official school to help them pass exams to get to higher grades**"?

Comment: If I am not mistaken. "Сhildren" is a subject. "To help them" implies another (missing) subject who help them. So I think "them" needs to be changed to "themselves". Am I right?

Comment: @xyz: No. I have a stick to help me walk: not to help *myself* walk.

Answer (score 1):

We might say one of the following:

"Children in Asia often have private tuition outside school-hours to help them attain higher grades in their exams"

"In order to attain higher grades in their exams, children in Asia often have home tutoring after school."

"Parents in Asia often engage home tutors to help their children attain higher grades in their exams."

*get* would be less formal than *attain*, but *attain* is more precise.

In the US "outside *of* school-hours" is more common than "outside school-hours."

Thank you for explaining your question so clearly.

Comment: BTW, "tuition" meaning "tutoring" is rare in US English, where "tuition" almost always refers to the *price charged* for attending a school.

Comment: @nanoman: Well well. So it does. I'll try and remember that. Thanks :-)